# vim horizontal and vertical splits from command line

Tags: vim, split

I'm trying to open 3 files in vim from the command line. I'd like one file on the left with a vertical split between it and the other two files, the remaining two files would be horizontally split.

```
  | 2
1 |---
  | 3
```

I know I can use the command `vim -O Notes.markdown -O Plan.markdown` to open the first two files in a vertical split and once I'm in I can switch to the second file with `ctl w` and then use the command `split History.markdown` to achieve what I want, but I'd like to be able to do it all in one line from the command line.

I tried using the command `vim -O Notes.markdown -O Plan.markdown -c split History.Markdown` which gets close, but it splits the first and second file leaving the 3rd on the right side of the vertical split.

The thing I can't figure out is if I can tell vim to use the `ctl` key from the command line so I could run something like `... -c <switchwindowcommand> | split History.markdown`. Is there a way to specify the control key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to do this; the key is `:wincmd`, which lets you execute arbitrary window commands.

Here, I first create three vertical splits, and then use `<C-W>H` to move the first window to a full-height vertical split on the left:

```
$ vim -o 1 2 3 -c "wincmd H"
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
:help windcmd
```

For example:

```
vim a.txt -c "vs b.txt | sp c.txt" -c "wincmd h"
```

Comment: Thanks, at first I was running into an error because I was trying to type `help windcmd`  and then noticed the different syntax in your example. The example you gave opened the split on the left side instead of the right, but it definitely sent me off in the right search direction. Thank you!